# Silverlight tcp socket never calls back the second time, unless I put a breakpoint on the connectasync call

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, debugging, asyncsocket

I have a method that attempts to connect.  I'm currently testing connection failure.  If it fails, the user is offered a retry button.  If I press it, m_tcpSocket.ConnectAsync(m_connectArgs); is called again, but I never get a callback.

However, if I put a breakpoint at the ConnectAsync call, the callback will occur.

Is there some cleanup I need to explicitly do that is done automatically when a breakpoint is hit in visual studio?

Thank you.

-Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Completed` event on the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` is not always called.   You sould check the boolean return value of your call to `ConnectAsync`.

A `false` value indicates that the connection request has completed synchronously, the properties on the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` will be ready for inspection and the `Completed` event will not fire.

Comment: What would cause it to complete synchronously?  The method is named ConnectAsync, implying it should happen asynchronously.

Comment: @Nikhil:  It may be called `ConnectAsync` but its clearly capable of completing synchronously as well, if your code doesn't account for that it could well fail in real world use.   What would cause it complete synchronously? I don't know the documentation doesn't say and I don't know enough about networking internals to even guess.